# Angular 5 input additional text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I got a combobox with an input field that - once an entry from the list was selected - not just the list entry should be displayed in the input field but also additional information.

To clarify: I do not mean a placeholder that vanishes once an entry was selected or a hint that moves to a corner of the field, but a piece of text that provides further information for the selected entry.

E.g.:

```
[ 12345 (additional information) ]
| 1                              |
| 12                             |
| 123                            |
| 1234                           |
| 12345                          |
+--------------------------------+
```

The list items are objects - so I already got the additional information but I don't want to just put the additional text in the input field (along with the actual '12345' data) cause the user is only interested in editing the number. I just want it to appear there as an information for the user.

So if the user would click into the input field - in a situation such as the one described above in the (E.g.) visualization - the '(additional information)' would disappear and only the '12345' would remain to be edited. The user could easily change it to '1234' then without having to remove the '(additional information)' part.

So the additional information text would have to move to the right - depending on the actual length of the number to the left and also be abbreviated (...) if it were too long for the input field.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a classic master-detail view. What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: My specific problem is that I do not know how to attach the additional information text to the actual content of the input field without actually adding it to its value. So that value only contains '12345' and nothing else, yet the 'additional information' text should still be displayed if the input field is not focused. I am assuming that that cannot be done and I have to use some sort of overlay, but since it needs to be on the right hand side of the '12345' value it needs to be adaptive.